# How to clear or remove the file data on Onedrive or Excel using Logic app?

Tags: excel, onedrive, azure-logic-apps, azure-appservice

I need to schedule for an everyday run,
once it ran and sent a mail, the excel or onedrive data need to clear.
[image]

[image]

updated each row from another logic app with the help of excel header.

Comment: May I know the content of your file(excel) ? Is it a table ? or rows ? or anything else ?

Comment: Need to delete rows, where i am updated each row from another logic app.

Comment: Delete all of the rows ? and all of the rows are in a  table in your excel ?

Comment: And do you mind delete the table ? Or you just want to delete the rows in table ?

Comment: just want to delete all the rows, table and table header helps for the next runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't find an action in logic app or a rest api of excel which can delete all of the rows directly. So I think we can just loop "[Delete a row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#delete-a-row)" action to delete the rows one by one. Please refer to my logic app as below:

**1.** First I use "List rows present in a table" action to list all of the rows.
[image]

**2.** Then my logic app show as this:
[image]

The "Condition" inside the "For each" is to judge if `Column1` is null. If the value of `Column1` is null, the "**Delete a row**" action will show error message.

In "Delete a row" action, I choose `Column1` as "**Key Column**" and put param `Column1` into "**Key Value**" box.
[image]

**3.** After running the logic app, all of the rows will be deleted. You can add these steps under your "**Send an email(v2)**" action. Or if you want to do it in another logic app, you can use "[When a new email arrives (V3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/office365/#when-a-new-email-arrives-(v3))" as the trigger of the logic app.